# Joda : UTC to User's locale with daylight saving offset

Tags: java, postgresql, timezone, jodatime, playframework-2.2

I have a `java.util.Date` stored as `2014-11-08 13:45:00` in my PostgreSQL field. (it is UTC)

I want to display it : at least with "Europe/Paris" timezone, with should bet 14:45

I tried

> DateTimeFormat.fullDateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Paris")).print(new DateTime(myJavaDate));

And some other combinations like this without success.

Better, if it could work with dynamical `Locale` instead of hardcoded `TimeZone` it would be perfect.

Thanks

**EDIT** : 
To write it in DB, I use Ebean :

```
SimpleDateFormat parserSDF=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss aaa", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date myJavaDate = parserSDF.parse(strDate);
...
bean.date = myJavaDate;
bean.save();
```

In my table, it's a `timestamp without time zone` column (Ebean autogenerated)

Comment: How is it stored in PostgreSQL? Is the timezone information stored along with the date too?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I parse a string to get the java.util.Date, then I store it with Ebean (see my edit)

Comment: @fge Actually, Postgres *never stores time zone* information with the date-time value. The SQL type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is a misnomer. The real meaning is "with respect for time zone" in that it uses any passed time zone info to adjust to UTC. The other SQL type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` ignores any passed time zone offset info (a bad idea btw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working solution

```
public String getTime(){
    Locale locale = Controller.request().acceptLanguages().get(0).toLocale();

    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(betDate, DateTimeZone.UTC);
    dateTime = dateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Paris"));
    return DateTimeFormat.shortTime().withLocale(locale).print(dateTime);
}

public String getDate(){
    Locale locale = Controller.request().acceptLanguages().get(0).toLocale();

    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(betDate, DateTimeZone.UTC);
    dateTime = dateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Paris"));
    return DateTimeFormat.shortDate().withLocale(locale).print(dateTime);
}
```